# Work with value only json and json-java

Tags: java, json

I am using the json-java library at https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java to parse some json files. i am reading the file into a string, and then sending it to `JSONObject()`. when the json file contains an object, such as:

`{
    "days" : 365
}`

it works fine. my problem is with 'value only' json, or 'json text'. according to the RFC http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt all of these are valid json text values:

> Here are three small JSON texts containing only values:
>
> "Hello world!"
>
> 42
>
> true

however when calling `jsonObject` the following error is thrown

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

that is with me calling

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("Hello world!");
```

it seems to work with number as number

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(42);
```

but not number presented as string

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("42");
```

the same is true of

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(true);
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("true");
```

is there an issue when parsing the strings? or am i doing it incorrectly? this problem arose because i am reading the contents of a file, into a string, then sending the built string of information to the `JSONObject`. 
this means
`"Hello World!"` never works, but it also means 
`42` never works, because after it is read in from the file, it becomes `"42"`, and it breaks since it now sees it as a string.

is there a way to use the library to also parse just 'json text' input?

Comment: I suspect the library is try to use the string as a key instead of the string value, this seems like a very odd use case for JSON. Why do you want to have only one single value in a JSON object?

Comment: Yup. It'd be better to do pass the file as { fileContents: "<Put that stuff here>" }, then it's always a JSON object.

Comment: It's a good question though. RFC 7159 plainly states that "A JSON parser MUST accept all texts that conform to the JSON grammar" so the question becomes (1) why doesn't JSON-java support this, is he misusing the API, or (2) where can he find an RFC 7159 compliant parser (which is unfortunately out of scope for SO...).

Comment: That said, Google's gson library seems to parse value-only JSON text just fine, `Integer fromJson = create.fromJson("6", Integer.class);`. This is a popular library, so I'd just use that.

Answer (score 0):

This saved my life

```
    // Serialization
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    gson.toJson(1); // ==> 1
    gson.toJson("abcd"); // ==> "abcd"
    gson.toJson(new Long(10)); // ==> 10
    int[] values = { 1 };
    gson.toJson(values); // ==> [1]

    // Deserialization
    int one = gson.fromJson("1", int.class);// ==> 1
    Integer oneInteger = gson.fromJson("1", Integer.class);// ==> 1
    Long oneLong = gson.fromJson("1", Long.class);// ==> 1
    Boolean bool = gson.fromJson("false", Boolean.class); // ==> false
    String str = gson.fromJson("\"abc\"", String.class);// ==> "abcd"
    String[] anotherStr = gson.fromJson("[\"abc\"]", String[].class);// ==> ["abc"]
```